# Link OpenSSL FIPS compliant (libcrypto.a) with another static library

Tags: openssl, static-libraries, fips, unix-ar

I am using `OpenSSL 1.0.2t` with `FIPS Object Module 2.0.16`. I have taken the source code and complied both and I have `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` generated.
In my use case I need `libcrypto.a`. I have a project which generates `libapi.a` and it will be given to the customers. `libapi.a` depends on some Boost libraries; what we do is, we get boost objects using `ar x libboost_somelib.a` and we add those objects into `libapi.a`.

1. I need to link `libcrypto.a` also to `libapi.a` should I do the same thing? Use `ar x libcrypto.a` and add all the object files to `libapi.a`?
2. Am I violating any FIPS compliance rules here?

Comment: The rules for FIPS compliance are extremely strict.  Any change invalidates the FIPS compliance, officially.  That would probably include repackaging the FIPS-compliant library in the way you propose (whether it makes sense or not technically).

Comment: So how can I link a static library of openssl Libcryto.a to my projects Libapi.a?

Comment: As I understand it, you’d provide two libraries and instruct your users to link with both.  Other people may have different views. Have you checked the OpenSSL site to see whether it gives guidance?